# Remotely powering UE Boom 2 from MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, remote-control

The wireless [UE Boom 2](http://www.ultimateears.com/en-gb/ueboom2) can be remotely powered on/off through the [UE MEGABOOM iPhone app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/ue-megaboom/id919613913?mt=8) and that's very useful in some cases.

It would be great to be able to do the same but from a MacBook, but Logitech didn't release such an app for macOS. I believe this should technically be feasible from any device with a Bluetooth 4 + LE device (which my MBP Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014 has).

Would you know how this could be achieved, through a Bluetooth software or script?

#### What I found so far:

This is what my Mac shows for the UE in System Information > Bluetooth

```
UE MEGABOOM:
  Address:          88-C6-26-89-57-B3
  Major Type:       Audio
  Minor Type:       Headphones
  Services:         Headset, Wireless iAP, LWACP, Hands-Free unit
  Paired:           Yes
  Configured:       Yes
  Connected:        No
  Manufacturer:     Cambridge Silicon Radio (0x8, 0x307D)
  Firmware Version: 0xFFFF
  Vendor ID:        0x000A
  Product ID:       0xFFFF
  Class of Device:  0x04 0x06 0x240418
  EDR Supported:    Yes
  eSCO Supported:   Yes
  SSP Supported:    Yes
```

I've tried [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/lightblue/id639944780) but it can't show the available services for the UE:

[image]

Comment: Let's see where this goes to. As long as we are looking at tools/ways accessible to the end user, the question is fine here. If answers tend to require ObjC programming we can migrate it to StackOverflow.

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: Linking to some ideas in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/marcust/af93ff47899583f5a52f) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mlalkaka/bc066e55d59e445a310fa37b9a6a661c)